# Delphi TSysCharSet , iterate through set of char

Tags: delphi

I need to verify if a certain position in a string is part of a given valid charset.
My code does not compile, how to iterate through set of char?

```
function Valid_Char_at_Index(const CheckStr: string; CheckPos : Integer ; ValidNextChars: TSysCharSet)
  : boolean;
var
  mychar : Char;
begin
  Result := false;
  for  each mychar in ValidNextChars do
      if (CheckStr(Length(CheckStr)) =mychar ) then
        Result:= True;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not clear why you would expect `for each` to work at all, since Delphi doesn't have `for each` loops, as [stated in the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_Statements). The documentation or a simple WWW search reveals that the corresponding Delphi concept is the `for in` loop.

Second, I don't understand at all what you mean by `CheckStr(Length(CheckStr)) = mychar`. Surely the predicate needs to contain the character index? And this is a syntax error, since `CheckStr` isn't a function or type. In fact, you simply want to check if the `CheckPos`th character of `CheckStr` is `mychar`.

Putting all this together, we end up with

```pascal
function CheckCharAt(const AText: string; APos: Integer; ValidChars: TSysCharSet): Boolean;
var
  ValidChar: Char;
begin
  for ValidChar in ValidChars do
    if AText[APos] = ValidChar then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

But please note that this only works for ASCII (and 8-bit character sets), so basically non-typographic English only, because of the `TSysCharSet` being a `set of AnsiChar` -- and a `set of WideChar` being an impossible type (since `SizeOf(WideChar) = 2 > 1`).

A simple way to fix this is to use an *array* of characters instead:

```pascal
function CheckCharAt(const AText: string; APos: Integer; const ValidChars: array of Char): Boolean;
begin
  for var ValidChar in ValidChars do
    if AText[APos] = ValidChar then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

But in modern Delphi versions, you don't need to write your own function at all, since you can simply use the [`TCharHelper.IsInArray`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.IsInArray) method:

```pascal
'test'[2].IsInArray(['a', 'e'])
```

---

Bonus info: If you only work with `AnsiString`s (or ASCII-only `string`s), you should of course use [the `in` set operator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators):

```pascal
function CheckCharAt(const AText: AnsiString; APos: Integer; const ValidChars: TSysCharSet): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AText[APos] in ValidChars;
end;
```

But, as I stated above, a set of `WideChar` is not possible, so you have to abandon the entire `set` concept if you need more than 8-bit characters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate.  Use `CharInSet()`.

```
function Valid_Char_at_Index(const CheckStr: string; CheckPos : Integer ; ValidNextChars: TSysCharSet)
  : boolean;
begin
  Result := CharInSet(CheckStr[CheckPos],ValidNextChars);
end;
```